# PrimeVue Cannot use import statement outside a module when activating InertiaJS SSR mode

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

I want to apply Server Side Rendering aka `SSR` to my application for better SEO,  i installed the necessary tools to run `SSR` mode `https://inertiajs.com/server-side-rendering`, then i run the server with this command : `php artisan inertia:start-ssr`:

`results`:

```
(node:12588) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\node_modules\primevue\config\config.esm.js:1
import { FilterMatchMode } from 'primevue/api';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Node.js v20.10.0
```

`package.json` :

```
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build && vite build --ssr"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/vue3": "^1.0.0",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^1.0.0",
        "vite": "^5.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.4.0"
        ...
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/vue3": "^1.0.14",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.2",
        ...
    }
}
```

`App.js`:

```
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import { resolvePageComponent } from "laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers";
import "primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css";
import PrimeVue from "primevue/config";
import Toast from "primevue/toast";
import ToastService from "primevue/toastservice";





createInertiaApp({
    resolve: async (name) => {
        const page = await resolvePageComponent(
            `./Pages/${name}.vue`,
            import.meta.glob("./Pages/**/*.vue")
        );


        return page;
    },
    
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        const VueApp = createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) });
        return VueApp.use(plugin)
            .use(PrimeVue, { ripple: true })
            .use(ToastService)
            .component("Toast", Toast)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: "#4B5563",
    },
});
```

`ssr.js`:

```
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import createServer from "@inertiajs/vue3/server";
import { renderToString } from "@vue/server-renderer";
import { createSSRApp, h } from "vue";
import { resolvePageComponent } from "laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers";
import "primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css";
import PrimeVue from "primevue/config";
import Toast from "primevue/toast";
import ToastService from "primevue/toastservice";




createServer((page) =>
    createInertiaApp({
        page,
        render: renderToString,
        resolve: async (name) => {
            const page = await resolvePageComponent(
                `./Pages/${name}.vue`,
                import.meta.glob("./Pages/**/*.vue")
            );


            return page;
        },

        setup({ App, props, plugin }) {
            return createSSRApp({
                render: () => h(App, props),
            })
                .use(PrimeVue, { ripple: true })
                .use(ToastService)
                .component("Toast", Toast)
                .use(plugin);
        },
    })
);
```

`vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig, splitVendorChunkPlugin } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: "resources/js/app.js",
            ssr: "resources/js/ssr.js",

            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        splitVendorChunkPlugin(),
    ],
});
```

`Dashboard/Index`:

```
import { FilterMatchMode } from "primevue/api";
```

I used `cjs` and `esm` extensions for the files being imported, i also used `require` instead of `import`, i changed the extensions of the files being imported to `mjs`, but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who wasted ~6 hours on this since yesterday, I do not think its possible to get this library working with inertia SSR. At least personally I gave up. If someone does know a way I will be really glad to hear it.

The issue is only when serving through the SSR server. I also tried loading primevue only on the client app (app.js instead of ssr.js and with createApp instead of createSSRApp as I did not care sacrificing client-side hydration) and still the problem persists when I start the ssr server and serve a page with a primevue component it, immediately the error comes up and closes the ssr server.

I would suggest adding primevue in the name of your question to make it more clear and hopefully someone will have some insights soon